# How can I make iconv replace the input file with the converted output?

Tags: shell, text-processing, io-redirection

I have a bash script which enumerates through every *.php file in a directory and applies `iconv` to it. This gets output in STDOUT.

Since adding the `-o` parameter ( in my experience ) actually writes a blank file probably before the conversion takes place, how can I adjust my script so it does the conversion, then overwrites the input file?

```
for file in *.php
do
    iconv -f cp1251 -t utf8 "$file"
done
```

Comment: See also [Warning regarding “>”](//unix.stackexchange.com/q/159513/80216#186126).

Answer (score 94, accepted):

This isn't working because `iconv` first creates the output file (since the file already exists, it truncates it), then starts reading its input file (which is now empty). Most programs behave this way.

Create a new, temporary file for the output, then move it into place.

```
for file in *.php
do
    iconv -f cp1251 -t utf8 -o "$file.new" "$file" &&
    mv -f "$file.new" "$file"
done
```

If your platform's `iconv` doesn't have `-o`, you can use a shell redirection to the same effect.

```
for file in *.php
do
    iconv -f cp1251 -t utf8 "$file" >"$file.new" &&
    mv -f "$file.new" "$file"
done
```

[Colin Watson's `sponge` utility](https://web.archive.org/web/20160531054830/http://riva.ucam.org:80/~cjwatson/blog/2006/02/06) (included in [Joey Hess's moreutils](http://kitenet.net/~joey/code/moreutils/)) automates this:

```
for file in *.php
do
    iconv -f cp1251 -t utf8 "$file" | sponge "$file"
done
```

This answer applies not just to `iconv` but to any filter program. A few special cases are worth mentioning:

- GNU sed and Perl `-p` have a `-i` option to replace files in place.
- If your file is extremely large, your filter is only modifying or removing some parts but never adding things (e.g. `grep`, `tr`, `sed 's/long input text/shorter text/'`), and you like living dangerously, you may want to genuinely [modify the file in place](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/11067/is-there-a-way-to-modify-a-file-in-place) (the other solutions mentioned here create a new output file and move it into place at the end, so the original data is unchanged if the command is interrupted for any reason).

Comment: I'm not quite sure whether the authorship of `sponge` should be attributed exclusively to Joey Hess; it's the package `moreutils` that includes `sponge` that he maintains, but as regards the origin of `sponge`, by following the links from the homepage of `moreutils`, I've found it originally [posted and suggested for inclusion](http://riva.ucam.org/~cjwatson/blog/2006/02/06#2006-02-06-sponge) by Colin Watson: "Joey writes about the lack of new tools that fit into the Unix philosophy. My favourite of such things I've written is `sponge`" (Mon, 06 Feb 2006).

Comment: I use Mac OS, there is no -o option in iconv, I have to change ` iconv -f cp1251 -t utf8 -o "$file.new" "$file"` to `iconv -f cp1251 -t utf8 "$file" > "$file.new"`

Comment: Some commands, like `sort`, are pretty smart concerning `-o` parameter, and if they detect output file is the same as input they internally manage a temp file so it just works.

Answer (score 71):

An alternative is `recode`, which uses the libiconv library for some conversions. Its behavior is to replace the input file with the output, so this will work:

```
for file in *.php
do
    recode cp1251..utf8 "$file"
done
```

As `recode` accepts multiple input files as parameter, you can spare the `for` loop:

```
recode cp1251..utf8 *.php
```

Comment: Thanks, this deserves more upvotes. Just wondering where is stared in manual about the 2 dots between the encodings...

Comment: “REQUEST often looks like BEFORE..AFTER, with BEFORE and AFTER being charsets.” That manual is indeed hard to follow with all those double dots (which are part of the syntax) and triple dots (which mean more of this). An advice: try `info recode` instead. Is more verbose.

Comment: Note that `recode` program expects cp1251 encoded files to have CR-LF endings. If not, you have to run `unix2dos` program first.

Comment: Perfect! And working also with classical problem of Windows monopoly and non-cumpliance `recode WINDOWS1252..UTF8 *.csv`

Answer (score 4):

For now

```
find . -name '*.php' -exec iconv -f CP1251 -t UTF-8 {} -o {} \;
```

works like a charm

Comment: At first, I indeed thought it works. But it appears the output exceeding 32K is cut off, and with even more input it triggers core dumps.

Answer (score 2):

You can use find, at least this worked for me on Raspbian Stretch:

```
find . -type f -name '*php' -execdir iconv -f cp1251 -t UTF-8 '{}' -o '{}'.tmp \; -execdir mv '{}'.tmp '{}' \;
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a [simple example](https://gist.github.com/dedeexe/b222b932539ea373fb0c). It should give you a enough info to get started.

```
#!/bin/bash
#conversor.sh
#Author.....: dede.exe
#E-mail.....: dede.exe@gmail.com
#Description: Convert all files to a another format
#             It's not a safe way to do it...
#             Just a desperate script to save my life...
#             Use it such a last resort...

to_format="utf8"
file_pattern="*.java"

files=`find . -name "${file_pattern}"`

echo "==================== CONVERTING ===================="

#Try convert all files in the structure
for file_name in ${files}
do
        #Get file format
        file_format=`file $file_name --mime-encoding | cut -d":" -f2 | sed -e 's/ //g'`

        if [ $file_format != $to_format ]; then

                file_tmp="${unit_file}.tmp"

                #Rename the file to a temporary file
                mv $file_name $file_tmp

                #Create a new file with a new format.
                iconv -f $file_format -t $to_format $file_tmp > $file_name

                #Remove the temporary file
                rm $file_tmp

                echo "File Name...: $file_name"
                echo "From Format.: $file_format"
                echo "To Format...: $to_format"
                echo "---------------------------------------------------"

        fi
done;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use Vim in Ex mode:

```sh
ex -sc '%!iconv -f cp1251 -t utf8' -cx "$file"
```

1. `%` select all lines
2. `!` run command
3. `x` save and close

Answer (score 1):

One option is to use `perl`'s interface to `iconv` and its `-i` mode for inplace editing:

```
perl -MText::Iconv -i -pe '
  BEGIN{$i=Text::Iconv->new(qw(cp1252 UTF-8));$i->raise_error(1)}
  $_ = $i->convert($_)' ./*.php
```

With GNU `awk`, you can also do something like¹:

```
gawk -v cmd='iconv -f cp1252 -t utf-8' -i /usr/share/awk/inplace.awk '
  {print | cmd}; ENDFILE {close(cmd)}' ./*.php
```

The `ksh93` shell also has a `>;` operator for that which stores the output in a temp file which is renamed to the redirected file if the command was successful:

```
for f in *.php; do
  iconv -f cp1252 -t utf-8 < $f >; $f
done
```

---

<sup>¹ **do not use `-i inplace`** as `gawk` tries to load the `inplace` extension (as `inplace` or `inplace.awk`) from the current working directory first, where someone could have planted malware. The path of the `inplace` extension supplied with `gawk` may vary with the system, see the output of `gawk 'BEGIN{print ENVIRON["AWKPATH"]}'`</sup>