# Can I read and write to the same file in Linux without overwriting it?

Tags: bash, shell, stdout, stdin

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I make iconv replace the input file with the converted output?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/10241/how-can-i-make-iconv-replace-the-input-file-with-the-converted-output)

I frequently connect to amazon ec2 using their public DNS names 
(`ec2-12-34-56-78.compute-1.amazonaws.com`) and because of this my `known_hosts` file gets overwhelmed with a lot of `ec2` entries I will never use again.

I know I could probably use `sed -i` to edit in place but I wanted to use `grep` and so I did this:

```
grep -v ec2 ~/.ssh/known_hosts > ~/.ssh/known_hosts
```

That leaves `known_hosts` as an empty file. If I do:

```
grep -v ec2 ~/.ssh/known_hosts > ~/.ssh/tmp
mv ~/.ssh/tmp ~/.ssh/known_hosts
```

then things are fine, but I am confused why reading and writing to the same file leaves it blank, and if there is any way around this when using `grep`, `cat`, etc.

Comment: Even if the program were doing the redirection itself, opening the file for read and then for write before actually reading from it would result in reading nothing (unless the language's standard library speculatively prebuffered, but that means you can't configure the buffer first).  What were you expecting to happen?

Comment: Sounds good. Thanks. Why is this not part of your answer?

Comment: Because it's actually a related issue, not the original problem (the shell is doing the file create, so `grep` would not have a chance to do anything about it anyway).  I'm just confused as to how it would be expected to work in the first place.

Comment: This is not the first time I've experienced this, so I don't "expect" to to work anymore, but initially I assumed that input flows from left to right and you operate on it on the left side and then would output it to the file on the right side. Guess part of the problem is that years ago I was a windows user and something similar would work in DOS.

Comment: Even DOS (2 and up) would do "the wrong thing" in most circumstances, although it at least would do the speculative prebuffer in many cases so you would see it appeart to work if the file was small enough; moreover, DOS 2 and later had shell redirection in `COMMAND.COM` and so had the overwrite happen before the command even ran.

Comment: Well thank goodness for `sponge` then :)

Comment: What's wrong with `sed -i /ec2/d`?

Comment: @ephemient - nothing is wrong with that for this specific example.

Comment: @Gilles - I believe that question is written with too much specificity to be found or read when searching for the core of the problem being discussed here.

Comment: @cwd Hence the value of having this one closed as a duplicate, with a highly-visible link to the other question.

Comment: @Gilles - wouldn't you want to have the more versatile question stay open?

Comment: @cwd It's better to use the one with the best answers. (I'm not sure I picked the right one, I have an easier time finding my own answers so I'm biased.) But it doesn't matter much.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

There is a utility called `sponge` that is a part of the [moreutils](http://kitenet.net/~joey/code/moreutils/) suite. It was made for this exact purpose.

```
grep -v ec2 ~/.ssh/known_hosts | sponge ~/.ssh/known_hosts
```

Comment: Why not just piping to `cat`? Like: `... | cat > ~/.ssh/known_hosts` ?

Comment: `cat` can write to its output at any time; if it writes past the point at whatever is on the other side of the pipe has read, then you will read in what you wrote instead of the original file contents. That is what makes sponge special. It buffers its input until `stdin` closes, then writes.

Comment: This might be interesting: If `sponge` isn't available, you could emulate it using `sed`:  `... | sed ':a;N;ba'`

Comment: sponge is also part of [sbase](http://git.suckless.org/sbase/tree/README)

Answer (score 10):

Redirections are done by the shell, before the command runs.  This means that the shell is told to truncate the file before `grep` gets a chance to read it.  There is no way around this if you are using shell redirection.