# Sed Usage: Add shebang missing from first line of script

Tags: bash, shell, command-line, sed, text

I have a `*.sh` script that's missing the shebang from the first line. Can I fix it with `sed`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Insert (`i`) the shebang with `sed`, in place operation:

```
sed -i '1 i #!/bin/bash' file.sh
```

With backing up the original file with a `.bak` extension:

```
sed -i.bak '1 i #!/bin/bash' file.sh
```

Replace `#!/bin/bash` with actual shebang you want.

**Example:**

```
% cat foo.sh
echo foobar

% sed '1 i #!/bin/bash' foo.sh 
#!/bin/bash
echo foobar
```

Comment: Just curious, could you get it working on empty files too somehow?

Comment: @rudimeier Not of my knowledge, no.

Comment: could do something like:  if [[ -z $(<file.sh) ]] ; then echo '#!/bin/bash' > file.sh ; else sed '1 i #!/bin/bash' file.sh ; fi

Comment: @Stephan If you want like that,  just do: `sed '1 i #!/bin/bash' file.sh || echo '#!/bin/bash' > file.sh`

Comment: The downside to that approach is it will overwrite the contents of file.sh if the sed command fails for any reason (I/O issue, for example.)  But yah, that's the general concept I was suggesting.

Comment: @Stephan yes, just to get the idea going, and thousand other ways indeed for checking.

Comment: BTW just noticed that executing a zero file just works. Don't know if actually executing the shell is important for the OP ;)

Comment: OP wants a shebang. Is this `bash` or `sh`?

Answer (score 2):

Using `bash` and `cat` (not in-place):

```
cat <(echo '#!/bin/sh') foo.sh
```

Or in-place using GNU awk >= 4.1:

```
awk -i inplace 'BEGINFILE{print "#!/bin/sh"}{print}' foo.sh
```

Comment: For the first one `{ echo '#! /bin/sh -'; cat foo.sh; }` or `echo '#! /bin/sh -' | cat - foo.sh` would make it more straightforward (and portable) (and more efficient for the first one) IMO

Comment: @Stéphane Chazelas: thx, regarding `{ echo '#! /bin/sh -'; cat foo.sh; }`, this was my first version but I hate using `cat` (con**cat**enate) for only one file. In zsh it would work like this `{ echo '#! /bin/sh -'; <foo.sh; }`. Nothing similar is portable I guess. However I think I should remove my non-inplace version since OP wants to edit the file.

Comment: Note that zsh's `<foo.sh` actually calls `pager < foo.sh`

Comment: @rudimeier Thanks for these alternative solutions. If the first one works, I could probably just add something like; `>foo-1.sh` to the end, no?.

Comment: @tjt263 No, this does not work in general. See http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/36261/can-i-read-and-write-to-the-same-file-in-linux-without-overwriting-it

Comment: @rudimeier It's writing to a different file. `-1`

Comment: Ah sorry I've misread it!