# Redirecting head output for update hosts file

Tags: io-redirection, hosts, head

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I make iconv replace the input file with the converted output?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/10241/how-can-i-make-iconv-replace-the-input-file-with-the-converted-output)

I'm writing a script to change the content of my `hosts` file but I got stuck on the `head` output redirection.

If I do `head -n -1 hosts >hosts` my `hosts` file will result empty and yes, it has more than 1 line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because your shell truncates the file when you redirect to it. This happens before head gets a chance to read it.

You can either use a temporary file:

```
head -n1 hosts > hosts.tmp && mv hosts.tmp hosts
```

Or use `sponge` from the moreutils packate:

```
head -n1 hosts | sponge hosts
```