# copy the pattern of awk and paste it next line

Tags: linux, bash, awk, sed

I have many txt files in a folder. Each file contains one line in this format;

> 8852 0.53451 0.55959 0.65494 0.36047

I would like to add, in the next line, a fixed number and the rest 4 columns copying from the original line, like so

> 8852 0.53451 0.55959 0.65494 0.36047
>
> 9997 0.53451 0.55959 0.65494 0.36047

So far I managed to add 9997 by the below command inside the folder

`find *.txt -exec sh -c 'echo "9997" >> $0' {} \;`

and managed to copy the rest 4 columns by

```
for files in .; do awk '{$1=""; print substr($0,2)}' *.txt;done
```

but it prints out in the output and not in the next line in each file.

I haven't managed to put them together yet and felt like I come so close but maybe in a wrong direction. I tried awk '{print "\n"$2,$3,$4,$5}'but it also didn't work.

Any help is appreciated! Thank you.

Comment: Are you trying to update the files in one directory or recursively update files in this directory and all directories under it?

Comment: @Ed in this directory and other directories next to it. sorry for late reply. thank you for your suggestions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given [your comment](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/528272/copy-the-pattern-of-awk-and-paste-it-next-line#comment977651_528272) that you want to update files `in this directory and other directories next to it.`, lets assume you have a directory under which there are other directories under which there are the files you want to modify. This is how you'd do that after cd-ing to that top level directory:

```
find . -maxdepth 2 -mindepth 2 -exec awk -i inplace '{print} $1==8852{$1=9997; print}' {} +
```

The above uses GNU awk for "inplace" editing and GNU find for `+`. If you don't have GNU tools then, assuming your file names don't contain newlines:

```
tmp=$(mktemp)
while IFS= read -r file; do
    awk '{print} $1==8852{$1=9997; print}' "$file" > "$tmp" &&
    mv "$tmp" "$file"
done < <(find . -maxdepth 2 -mindepth 2) )
rm -f "$tmp"
```

If you don't want to change the timestamp on files that don't containing `8852` then:

```
tmp=$(mktemp)
while IFS= read -r file; do
    awk '$1==8852{f=1; exit} END{exit !f}' "$file" &&
    awk '{print} $1==8852{$1=9997; print}' "$file" > "$tmp" &&
    mv "$tmp" "$file"
done < <(find . -maxdepth 2 -mindepth 2) )
rm -f "$tmp"
```

Comment: thanks for the proper way to make it works. not a one liner finally! anyway, to update all other directories from the top level directory, I have to modify it further, as not all the directories has 8852 to start with. I'll try to figure that out. Thank you

Comment: I meant other directories have other numbers that's not 8852, but I also want to change them :) I think I really have to write a script for that e.g. directories with files that contain 26053 0.xxxxx 0.xxxxx 0.xxxxx 0.xxxxx also needs to add in the next line 9997 0.xxxxx 0.xxxxx 0.xxxxx 0.xxxxx

Comment: OK, feel free to ask a new question with more accurate/representative sample input/output if you have a question about how to do that.

Comment: yes, will figure out the overview of what I want and will see if I can do it myself first. thanks again.

Answer (score 3):

I'd suggest `awk '{print; $1 = 9997; print}'`

```
$ echo '8852 0.53451 0.55959 0.65494 0.36047' | awk '{print; $1 = 9997; print}'
8852 0.53451 0.55959 0.65494 0.36047
9997 0.53451 0.55959 0.65494 0.36047
```

You mention applying the transformation to multiple files: you can do so either using a loop

```
for f in *.txt; do  awk '{print; $1 = 9997; print}' "$f"; done
```

or (recursively) using `find`

```
find . -name '*.txt' -exec awk '{print; $1 = 9997; print}' {} \;
```

however unless you have a recent version of GNU Awk with the `-i inplace` extension, the results will be concatenated and written to standard output.

Comment: yes I tried the one above, and the results are written to standard output. thank you for your proper answer.

Answer (score -1):

So you have many files and they have one line in the below format.

> 8852 0.53451 0.55959 0.65494 0.36047

Now you want to open the file and replace the first column with a value of your choice and leave the rest as it is, then append it to the next line.

> 8852 0.53451 0.55959 0.65494 0.36047
>
> 9997 0.53451 0.55959 0.65494 0.36047

If I get this question right, the below should work.

``` for file in ``find . -name "*.txt"``; do awk '{print "\n9997 "$2,$3,$4,$5}' $file >> $file; done ```

Get all the files in a folder, with awk read the file and take 2345 columns and for the first column add your value and append it to the same file.

Apologies if I got your question wrong.

Comment: Not only is this a bad idea due to parsing the output of `ls` but it's also going to give a bunch of errors iif there are any directories inside of the folder and if there are any files (or directories) with spaces in them. It would also perform the operateion on every file in that directory whether it's needed or not. You also don't need the double quotes in between the column parameters for awk as a space as a field separator can be denoted with a comma.

Comment: I tried. it didn't work. maybe something to do with ``ls -1`` as @Nasir mentioned? but yes you understand what I want correctly

Comment: @NasirRiley, thanks for the comment. I'm a newb myself. I will edit the answer.

Comment: @Pimpwhippa, what is the output when you execute this?

Comment: It just returns, gives no output. then I go nano into a few random files. nothing happens there either. I just copied pasted what you typed.

Comment: Take out the extra apostrophes before and after ls -1, like this - for file in `ls -1 *txt*`; do awk '{print "\n9997 "$2,$3,$4,$5}' $file >> $file; done

Comment: @Vignesh SP yes, now it works. Thank you! nonetheless, if it is not recommended to parse the output of ls, what else could be done instead? just would like to know for educational purpose..

Comment: Well, Riley was mentioning that  ls will provide everything from the directory as output which includes directory and all. We can fixe this by what exactly we want. Now all you want is files with .txt extension. So we can ask ls to provide files only with .txt extension by adding `ls -1 *txt*`. Hopefull this solves the downside of using ls. Other than this, I do not see any downsides in using ls.

Comment: @VigneshSP The downsides are that your command would break if any of the files contain spaces and/or if there are any files that contain the string `txt` that you don't want to operate on. A Google search will give plenty of examples of why parsing `ls` isn't a good idea starting with this one: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/128985/why-not-parse-ls-and-what-do-to-instead

Comment: @NasirRiley I guess piping ls to sed may solve the space issue? like this? `ls -1 | sed 's/\ /\\\ /g'`

Comment: @VigneshSP No, because that's still parsing `ls` which is what you want to avoid.

Comment: @VigneshSP combining the awk print to the find command?

Comment: @NasirRiley How about `find . -name "*.txt"` than `ls`? Would that work?

Comment: @Pimpwhippa, didn't understand what you meant.

Comment: @VigneshSP something like find *.txt -exec sh -c 'echo "\n"9997 $(awk '{print $2,$3,$4,$5}')' >> $0' {} \;

Comment: @Pimpwhippa `for file in `find . -name "*.txt"`; do awk '{print "\n9997 "$2,$3,$4,$5}' $file >> $file;done` this works too. We can find so many other ways to do this if we sit and do a research on this  :p

Comment: @VigneshSP hahaha thanks for researching this with me! now we can move on to the next task! ;D

Comment: Do not execute this code. So many bugs/anti-patterns in so little code - see https://mywiki.wooledge.org/Quotes, http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001, http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799, /xrat/V4_xcu_chap02.html#tag_23_02_06_03, https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/10241/133219, and I'm sure there's more...

Comment: oh thank you @Ed Morton